# issue with java while statement?

Tags: java, while-loop

My code compiles correctly. When I run my program the output asks me to enter weight   of package. If I enter a negative number the program asks me to enter weight again, but won't stop to let me enter another number.

I think the problem is in the "while" statement but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dcrawford_Shipping
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int weight, distance, distancex;
    double rate, price;
    rate = 0.00;

    System.out.print("Please enter package weight: ");
    weight = input.nextInt();


    while (weight <= 0 || weight >= 61)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter package weight: ");
    }

    if (weight <= 10 && weight >= 1 )
    {
        rate = 5.01;
    }
    else if ( weight <= 20 && weight >= 11 )
    {
        rate = 7.02;
    }
    else if ( weight <= 30 && weight >= 21 )
    {
        rate = 9.03;
    }
    else if ( weight <= 40 && weight >= 31 )
    {
        rate = 11.04;
    }
    else if ( weight <= 60 && weight >= 41)
    {
        rate = 15.00;
    }

 System.out.print("Please enter distance: ");
    distance = input.nextInt();

    while ( distance <= 0 )
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter distance: ");
        }

    distancex = ( distance / 100 ) + 1;
    price = ( distancex * rate );

    System.out.printf("Your total shipping cost for %d miles is $%.2f\n", distance, price);
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful with the integer division.

Comment: You're not reading the new distance inside your while...

Comment: Your while loop has a single statement in it, a println.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask the user to enter the weight again inside of the while loop.

```
while (weight <= 0 || weight >= 61) {
    System.out.print("Please enter package weight: ");
    weight = input.nextInt();
}
```

You could also use a do-while loop:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter package weight: ");
    weight = input.nextInt();
} while (weight <= 0 || weight >= 61);
```

If you use the do-while loop, you can remove the first time you ask and the while loop. It's a slightly more compact way of doing it.